# Ember template without div wrapper

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, semantic-ui

Semantic UI (a HTML5 component library) provides the [Sitebar](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/usage) component, which needs a specific page structure directly below `<body>`.

Since Ember introduced HTMLBars, it wraps all templates' content within another `<div>` tag before injecting it into the DOM, e.g.

```
<div id="ember389" class="ember-view"><!-- original template's content comes here --></div>
```

which makes using the above mentioned Sitebar and comparable components virtually unusable.

There have been similar questions for older Ember versions, but their answers do not work anymore, as `Views` have been retired. Ember still provides the private [_MetamorphView](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.0.1/packages/ember-views/lib/compat/metamorph_view.js#L38) class for "templates without wrappers", but besides the fact that it is also deprecated, I don't now how to incorporate them into my `Route`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: PS: I would even resurrect good old metamorph script tags! (:

Comment: If this is an Ember component, you can just put `tagName: ""` in the component .js file and it won't generate a div around your template. Eventually you won't have to do this but this is the workaround for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually not that much hard as you think. All you need is to make some slight changes in the [component](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/components/). (Assume you're using Ember 2.x and want to make side bar as component)

For Eg.

```
// app/components/side-bar.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['ui', 'sidebar']
});

// app/templates/components/side-bar.hbs
{{yield}}

// usage 
// app/templates/application.hbs
{{#side-bar}}
    // your sidebar contents go here
{{/side-bar}}
<div class="pusher">
    // Your site's actual content
    {{outlet}}
</div>
```

If the side bar isn't necessary to be a component, then it'll be lot simpler

```
// app/templates/application.hbs
<div class="ui sidebar">
  // ...
</div>
<div class="pusher">
  // Your site's actual content
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

EDIT - answer to the comment

> A sidebar can be initialized inside any element, not just a page's body.

http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#using-a-custom-context

Comment: Thanks! :-) It's my understanding that the route's template (in which the component may be included), e.g. `application.hbs`, will already be wrapped within said div when being imported into `index.html`. Is there a way to circumvent this or directly include the component into `index.html` in order to benefit from your solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

    /**
     * No default div around the element.
     */
    tagName: ''

});
```

Answer (score 1):

set empty tagName parameter
in .hbs

```
{{component-name tagName=''}}
```